# Atlas search not matching partial search if field contains _

Tags: mongodb-atlas-search

Given the following Atlas Search Index and example data…

**Atlas Search Index**

```
{
  mappings: {
    dynamic: false,
    fields: {
      content: {
        tokenization: 'edgeGram',
        type: 'autocomplete'
      },
      title: {
        tokenization: 'edgeGram',
        type: 'autocomplete'
      }
    },
  },
  name: 'DocumentSearch',
}
```

**Example Data**

```
[
  { 
    _id: 1, 
    title: 'My first document', 
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
  },
  { 
    _id: 2, 
    title: 'My first_document', 
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
  },
]
```

I’m trying to searching for “document” and I’m expecting to get back both documents but getting back only the first.

**Search Query**

```
{
  $search: {
    index: 'DocumentSearch',
    compound: {
      minimumShouldMatch: 1,
      should: [
        {
          autocomplete: {
            path: 'title',
            query,
            score: { boost: { value: 4 } },
          },
        },
        {
          autocomplete: {
            path: 'content',
            query,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    highlight: {
      path: 'content',
    },
  },
}
```

What changes do I need to make to my query or index to support my desired outcome?